# Absolutely positioned text getting cut off in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, css-position

http://cure.org/brant/

On the right side of the page, I have some text getting cut off in IE7. It is the HTML text numbers on top of the green tags. If you view with IE7 (or IE8 in developer mode for IE7) you'll see them getting cut off just below where they should start.

I have a feeling it may have something to do with the padding on the enclosing anchor element and an IE7 bug I just may not be aware of.

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in that the height is 30px the font-size is 32px and the padding-top is 25px

SO the padding moves the text down 25px within that 30px height cutting off the all but the top 5px of your 32px font.

You will need to ajust the height to be 25px+32px = 57px instead.

EDIT: the real killer here is the line-height:14px though - so you only see 14px of the font.
LI.lp-ask-butn-sm A:link

SO line-height:64px and height:60px and padding-top:5px and it shows up

Comment: NOTE: Your padding-top:25px is not really needed due to the vertical-aline:baseline;

Comment: Yup, that was it. I figured that out too. I removed the 14px line height from the containing anchor statement, then added an appropriate line height to the strong element, adjusted for top position and all was well. Thanks for your help mate!